# return boolean value from SQLQuery Java

Tags: java, hibernate

I have this method.

```
public boolean leLayoutNovo(String schema, int idUsuario) {
    Session session = this.getSessionPronta();
    try {

        String sql = "select layoutNovo from usuario where id = " + idUsuario;
        SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);



    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
}
```

In my case, layoutNovo its a boolean field in my table.

Is it possible to return directly the boolean value from my query?

Comment: There's `uniqueResult`, IIRC, but that returns `Object`. I mean, queries return results, which you then need to manage. I don't see what the big deal is--deal with the result(s) doing whatever conversions are necessary and return that.

Comment: I think uniqueResult works for me, im about to test it.
I just need the return of this method to be true or false but it has to be the exactly same value of the table column

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Scalars](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#d0e13646)

```
 String sql = "select layoutNovo from usuario where id = " + idUsuario;
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
sql.addScalar("layoutNovo",Hibernate.BOOLEAN);
```

With this